# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta de los registros de una tercera tabla?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lambda

Buenas, sigo estudiando Entity Framework.

La pregunta es, tengo 3 tablas, Expediente, Documentos y Archivos (Imágenes).

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es recuperar todos los archivos, de todos los documentos que pertenecen a un expediente.

Intenté algo como así:

```
public static List<Archivo> GetArchivo(BindingList<Documento> documento)
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        using (context)
        {
            List<Archivo> lista = new List<Archivo>();
            using (context)
            {
                foreach(var documentos in documento)
                {
                    return context.Archivos.Where(x => x.idDocumento == documentos.idDocumento).ToList();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

pero solo me devuelve los últimos 2. Hay alguna forma de hacer un acumulador u otro tipo de consulta?

Lo quiero para hacer filtros desde una lista sin estar recurriendo a la bd.

Comment: Lo que también puedes utilizar es Dapper, un framework para administrar bases de datos en código similar a EntityFramework pero mucho más rápido. Aquí te dejo la documentación sobre Dapper que puede que te sea de ayuda: [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar lo siguiente para obtener todos los documentos de un expediente dado. La tecnica que buscas se llama **eager loading** puedes encontrar más aquí [Eager Loading EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx). Deberias probar con la estructura de tu base de datos para ver si puedes cargar anticipadamente los archivos también.

```
var expendienteConDocumentos = context.Expediente
                                 .Where(b => b.IdExpediente == "identificador_expediente") 
                                 .Include(b => b.Documentos)
                                 //podrias intentar otro include para conseguir los archivos de los documentos
                                 .SingleOrDefault();
```

*NOTA:** La técnica de eager loading puede consumir bastante memoria, así que utilizala con precaución.

Otra alternativa, según se investigó para cargar los archivos y documentos en una sola consulta es:

```
var expendienteConDocumentos = context.Expediente
                                 .Where(b => b.IdExpediente == "identificador_expediente") 
                                 .Include(i => i.Documentos.Select(s => s.Archivos))
                                 .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Gracias, cómo obtener los documentos no es el problema jeje si no los archivos en esos documentos que le pertenecen a ese expediente.

Comment: Prueba con .Include(i => i.Documentos.Select(s => s.Archivos)) al parecer asi se pueden cargar anidadamente

Comment: jmmm entiendo... pero eso me devuelve una lista de expedientes. Cómo podría meterlo en una lista de archivos?

Comment: intenté declarar una lista de documentos e igualarla a expediente.Documentos, funcionó como me dijiste. Pero si quiero hacer un foreach(var doc in listadoc)
{
listaArchivo.Add(doc.Archivo);
}

me da error de que no puedo converir del tipo icollections Entidad.Archivo a Entidad.Archivo. Por lo que vuelvo al problema donde empecé.

Comment: En teoria te deberia devolver un único expediente con los documentos y archivos cargados. Con respecto al error significa que estas obteniendo una coleccion de Archivo sobre la que debes iterar para obtener cada uno de los objetos Archivo,